# googledrive unnest returns unused argument error

Tags: r

I am using [googledrive](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/) to get information about a list of files on a shared drive, and would like to `unnest(drive_resource)` into columns for purpose of exploring the data.

When I do so, I receive an error. Appears to be something about the class of nested list I am trying to unnest as columns. Any suggestions?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(googlesheets)

df <- drive_find(team_drive = "my_team_drive") 
unnest(df, drive_resource)

Error in as_tibble.dribble(output, .name_repair = "minimal") : 
  unused argument (.name_repair = "minimal")
```

Comment: What version of `tidyr` are you using? It would probably be best to show all the versions of the packages involved from your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Turns out the issue was with the nested object, and not with my call to `tidyr::unnest()`. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there is a [bug fix in dev](http://twitter.com/matthewdwood82/status/1217500566429077510) for the .name_repair issue.

A quick-and-dirty solution appears below, improvements welcome.

```r
df2 <- df %>%
  map_dfr(
    .x = .$drive_resource,
    .f = ~ unlist(.x) %>% enframe() %>% spread(name, value)
  ) %>%
  bind_cols(select(df, name:id))
```

If you only want the top level of that list object, the below is simpler. Especially good for team drives with a lot of users, since list of permissionIds gets turned into as many columns as you have users. Just call `unnest_wider()` for each of (parents, spaces, lastModifyingUser, capabilities, permissionIds, exportLinks, imageMediaMetadata, videoMediaMetadata) that you want to see information about.

Below courtesy of @JennyBryan

```r
df2 <- df %>%
  select(drive_resource) %>%
  unnest_wider(drive_resource)
```